# Laravel Telescope flooded by requests

Tags: laravel, laravel-telescope

I have Laravel Telescope running, and it gets requests from somewhere every 3 seconds.

[image: Screenshot]

Requests are:
/telescope/telescope-api/requests?before=&family_hash=&tag=&take=50
and
/telescope/telescope-api/requests?family_hash=&tag=&take=1

Does anyone know from where I got those requests and how to stop them?